# Codeigniter vote up

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Just want to increase the value in mysql table. Please see below the table. for example, my model should find the row with id 2, get the value of like column (5), increase it by one (5+1) and return the result (6). Could you please help me.

Here is my table:

[image]

Here is my model:

```
public function test($id){

    $this->db->select('like');
    $this->db->from('movies');   
    $this->db->where('id', $id);

    $data = array (
               'like' => " like + 1",
                  );

    $this->db->update('movies', $data); 

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1){
    return $query->result();
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the `select from` here.

[CodeIgniter Update reference](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update)

Try something like this:

```
 $this->db->where('id', $id);
 $this->db->set('like', 'like+1', FALSE);
 $this->db->update('movies');

 $idU = $this->db->insert_id();
 $r = $this->db->get_where('movies', array('id' => $idU));
 return $r->row();
```